# Como apresentar um componente somente na tela inicial?

Tags: emberjs

Dentro do `application.hbs` tenho um componente chamado `jus-hero`:

```
<header class="bg-leaf">
  {{jus-hero}}
</header>
<main class="l-main">
  {{outlet}}
</main>
```

Como renderizar este componente somente na página `index`? Essa configuração fica no arquivo `app/components/jus-hero.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução simples, depois de algumas buscas no GitHub.

Basta instalar o `ember install ember-truth-helpers` e fazer a verificação com o nome da rota:

```
{{#if (eq currentRouteName 'index')}}
  {{jus-hero}}
{{/if}}
```

Espero estar ajudando outros com a mesma dúvida :]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode definir a sua home como sendo alguma rota específica, que não a application route. Dessa forma, exibindo o componente em questão apenas nela.

Exemplo:

No seu arquivo router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', {
    path: '/'
  });
});
```

E no seu home.hbs (template da rota home)

```
{{!-- home.hbs --}}
<header class="bg-leaf">
  {{jus-hero}}
</header>
```

No application.hbs mantendo apenas

```
{{!-- application.hbs --}}

<main class="l-main">
  {{outlet}}
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar as rotas auxiliares.

Exemplo crie um template `app/templates/index.hbs`. Coloque o conteudo dentro dele

```
 {{jus-hero}}
```

No `application.hbs` deixe somente a casca

```
<main class="l-main">
  {{outlet}}
</main>
```

Quando a rota estive especificadamente dentro em `/` ele irá utilizar o index. Isso serve para subrotas também  exemplo `/products/id/index`.
referencia:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/subroutes/#toc_generating-a-nested-index-route